# How to remove first li from ul by using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i remove first `<li>` from `<ul>`
  please check my code

```
<ul>
 <li>bhanu</li>
 <li> hari</li>
 <li> codes</li>
<li> hari</li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to fetch data from  and find "hari" data in `<li>` then remove first `<li>` tag belongs to hari
 how can i do this

Comment: do you want to remove duplicate elements?

Comment: So you want to remove *just the first li* that contains "hari", and leave everything else alone?

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: I want to remove duplicate Elements but i don't want to delete last one in the duplicate elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so :

```
$('ul li:contains(hari)').first().remove();
```

get the list elements containing the string `hari`, and remove the first one

Comment: +1 But you know he'll say that works but it removes the wrong one when he inserts a list item with "bhari" in it :p

Comment: @Archer - ha ha, that's true, and it wouldn't suprise me at all!